# How can I prototype an Aluminum-clad board?

Tags: pcb, power-electronics, thermal

I have a fairly thermal-heavy design that I want to prototype on something resembling an aluminum-clad (or -core) board.  Alas, it's not FR-4 and the low-volume run costs are exorbitant.

What is a good way to prototype a thermal design on something "aluminum-clad-like"?  The actual count of high-dissipation components is quite low (about a dozen), so I was tempted to try to hack them on with bubblegum and maybe some electrically-insulating thermal epoxy, then run wires (previously dead-bugged) off to the rest of the circuit on a cheap FR-4 PCB.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Have you considered polyimide with a thermally-conductive adhesive?

Comment: Just using the polyimide for isolation in addition to thermal epoxy, or is double-sided polyimide tape available?

Comment: Would sheets of aluminum flashing work?

Comment: How exorbitant is exorbitant.  I see 5 3"x5" aluminum boards, 8 working day till ship, at about $260.

Answer (score 3):

If you're willing to live with design rules like the cheapest aluminum core board (single sided, with no plated through holes) you could buy the thinnest prototype board available (eg. 0.4mm) and simply laminate the blank side (or make it all floating copper) to a sheet of aluminum.

There are companies offering to prototype aluminum clad boards though, and I would expect the cost to be reasonable (from your perspective) if it's something that will eventually go to production.